# Applets for Geometry of Curves and Surfaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request

Are there any computer graphics applets available to illustrate things relevant to a course on curves and surfaces like tangent plane, principal curvature, Gaussian curvature, first and second fundamental forms, and Gauss-Bonnett?

I had hoped to use the book "Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces" by Banchoff and Lovett, which claims to have an interactive Java applet but the link is dead. Indeed, it seems to be a common trend that applets designed for a book or course become unusable within only a few years.

Comment: Math toolboxes like Mathematica and Matlab have built-in 3D plot viewers, as well as symbolic math libraries that let you compute the shapes you want to look at.

Comment: If the applet is dead, check the [Internet Archive](http://archive.org).

Comment: To close voters: note that the help center says questions about mathematical software are on-topic for this site.